# tensorflow: Error multiplying a sparse matrix with a dense matrix using tf.matmul

Tags: python, tensorflow, sparse-matrix

In the following code, I want dense matrix `B` to left multiply a sparse matrix `A`, but I got errors.

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

A = tf.sparse_placeholder(tf.float32)
B = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=(5,5))
C = tf.matmul(B,A,a_is_sparse=False,b_is_sparse=True)
sess = tf.InteractiveSession()
indices = np.array([[3, 2], [1, 2]], dtype=np.int64)
values = np.array([1.0, 2.0], dtype=np.float32)
shape = np.array([5,5], dtype=np.int64)
Sparse_A = tf.SparseTensorValue(indices, values, shape)
RandB = np.ones((5, 5))
print sess.run(C, feed_dict={A: Sparse_A, B: RandB})
```

The error message is as follows:

```
TypeError: Failed to convert object of type <class 'tensorflow.python.framework.sparse_tensor.SparseTensor'> 
to Tensor. Contents: SparseTensor(indices=Tensor("Placeholder_4:0", shape=(?, ?), dtype=int64), values=Tensor("Placeholder_3:0", shape=(?,), dtype=float32), dense_shape=Tensor("Placeholder_2:0", shape=(?,), dtype=int64)). 
Consider casting elements to a supported type.
```

What's wrong with my code?

I'm doing this following the [documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/matmul) and it says we should use `a_is_sparse` to denote whether the first matrix is sparse, and similarly with `b_is_sparse`. Why is my code wrong?

As is suggested by vijay, I should use `C = tf.matmul(B,tf.sparse_tensor_to_dense(A),a_is_sparse=False,b_is_sparse=True)`

I tried this but I met with another error saying:

```
Caused by op u'SparseToDense', defined at:
  File "a.py", line 19, in <module>
    C = tf.matmul(B,tf.sparse_tensor_to_dense(A),a_is_sparse=False,b_is_sparse=True)
  File "/home/mypath/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/sparse_ops.py", line 845, in sparse_tensor_to_dense
    name=name)
  File "/home/mypath/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/sparse_ops.py", line 710, in sparse_to_dense
    name=name)
  File "/home/mypath/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/gen_sparse_ops.py", line 1094, in _sparse_to_dense
    validate_indices=validate_indices, name=name)
  File "/home/mypath/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/op_def_library.py", line 767, in apply_op
    op_def=op_def)
  File "/home/mypath/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 2506, in create_op
    original_op=self._default_original_op, op_def=op_def)
  File "/home/mypath/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 1269, in __init__
    self._traceback = _extract_stack()

InvalidArgumentError (see above for traceback): indices[1] = [1,2] is out of order
[[Node: SparseToDense = SparseToDense[T=DT_FLOAT, Tindices=DT_INT64, validate_indices=true, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"](_arg_Placeholder_4_0_2, _arg_Placeholder_2_0_0, _arg_Placeholder_3_0_1, SparseToDense/default_value)]]
```

Thank you all for helping me!

Comment: Your indices should be in order change - indices = np.array([[3, 2], [1, 2]], dtype=np.int64) to indices = np.array([ [1, 2], [3,2]], dtype=np.int64). change the values also appropriately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `tf.matmul`, flags `a_is_sparse` and `b_is_sparse` do not indicate the operands being `SparseTensors`, but  instead, they are algorithmic hints to invoke more efficient ways to compute multiplication on two dense Tensors. In your code should be :

```
C = tf.matmul(B,tf.sparse_tensor_to_dense(A),a_is_sparse=False,b_is_sparse=True)
```

To matmul a `SparseTensor` and a `dense` Tensor, you can also use `tf.sparse_tensor_dense_matmul()` instead.